# Downloading Android Studio bundle on linux

Tags: android

Im using Ubuntu 14.4 LTS, and when go to offical site for downloading the complete android bundle [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) it always goes to other options instead of downloading(like in windows)?
Is there an issue here?

Comment: How about this page? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Answer (score 1):

I can only find these two those are not latest versiones:

ADT Bundle:
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

Android Studio:
http://dl.google.com/android/studio/install/0.8.6/android-studio-bundle-135.1339820-linux.tgz